# What will be the physical address of 000H and 29H ?

Tags: memory-address

What will be the physical address of 0000H assume this segment address and offset address is 29H ?

I am reading the Assembly Language Step by Step 3rd Edition, the answer of this question inside the book which i mentioned is 2DH Bytes But How ?

I took basic steps to to solve my self and here it is my result: 
0000 0000 0000 0010 1001 // segment address + offset addr (In Binary)
After calculation the result will be 41 in decimal and if we convert this to Hex it will be again 29H. Basically, the answer inside the book is 2DH, How ?

and there is another problem with 0001H which is segment address  and the offset address is 19H. The answer inside the book is 1DH, How ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you certain that it says `29H`, and not just `29` (which equals `1DH`)? If so, can you point to the exact page where it says this?

Comment: Page 89 Chapter Location,Location,Location :)

Comment: Book Link here : https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=veMTOpapeZkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Looks like a typo to me (i.e. like it was supposed to say 19H/29H instead of 1DH/2DH).

Comment: Oh, Sir did you checked the book content may be I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that it looks like a typo in the book.

Comment: Ok thanks :) Sir can you explain what is the correct answer ? 
BTW, if you can get the physical address of those above example.
sorry for bothering you :) 
thanks

Comment: The formula is `segment * 10H + offset`